# Filtering data in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created function that filters object by button click, everything is fine with that at component level. But, when I filter object and then go to next step and then go back I can't unfilter data. I'm operating at object from service.

Here is example code:

This is setter for parent component:

```
@Input()
  public set application(newApplication: Application) {
    this.applicationData = newApplication;
    if (newApplication) {
      this.policy = newApplication.pricingPolicy;
      this.originalPriceConfig = {...this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig};
      this.filteredPriceConfig = {...this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig};
      this.isRenew = !!(this.policy && this.policy.referenceId);
      this.referenceFrom = this.policy && this.isRenew ? this.policy.referenceFrom : null;
      this.referenceTo = this.policy && this.isRenew ? this.policy.referenceTo : null;
      this.dateFrom = this.policy && this.policy.from ? this.policy.from : null;
      this.dateTo = this.policy && this.policy.to ? this.policy.to : null;
      this.promotionalFrom = this.policy && this.policy.promotionFrom ? this.policy.promotionFrom : null;
      this.promotionalTo = this.policy && this.policy.promotionTo ? this.policy.promotionTo : null;
    }
  }
```

In that component i filter data like this:

```
private filterTableByChoosenProperty(): void {
    const sub: Subscription = this.pricingService.setChoosenProducts.subscribe((toggle: boolean) => {
      this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig = {...this.originalPriceConfig};
      if (toggle) {
        this.filteredPriceConfig = {...this.filterGroupByField('priceConfig', this.filteredPriceConfig, this.is(this.chosen()))};
        this.filteredPriceConfig = {...this.filterGroupByField('subGroup', this.filteredPriceConfig, (item) => this.checkIfPriceConfigHasElements(item.priceConfig) || this.checkIfGroupArrayHasElements(item.subGroup))};
        this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig = {...this.filteredPriceConfig};
      }
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(sub);
  }
```

How can I achive unfilter data when I go back to this component from different component?

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear the chosen property... set it to null or empty on ngOnInit of the component.

Comment: You may this property? setChoosenProducts, if yes this is not a correct answer In my opinion this is problem with this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig object reference

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting the existing object `this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig` in filter section. You must keep the original data untouched.

You can keep the clone of applicationData in input section. Look at the commented area

```
let originalApplicationData; //add new instance variable.
@Input()
  public set application(newApplication: Application) {
    this.applicationData = newApplication;
    this.originalApplicationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringif(newApplication)); //deep cloning the object
    this.originalApplicationData.
    this.applyFilter(newApplication);
    this.originalApplicationData.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig = this.applicationData.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig;
  }
```

Break your filter code into separate method

```
  applyFilter(newApplication){
       if (newApplication) {
          this.policy = newApplication.pricingPolicy;
          this.originalPriceConfig = {...this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig};
          this.filteredPriceConfig = {...this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig};
          this.isRenew = !!(this.policy && this.policy.referenceId);
          this.referenceFrom = this.policy && this.isRenew ? this.policy.referenceFrom : null;
          this.referenceTo = this.policy && this.isRenew ? this.policy.referenceTo : null;
          this.dateFrom = this.policy && this.policy.from ? this.policy.from : null;
          this.dateTo = this.policy && this.policy.to ? this.policy.to : null;
          this.promotionalFrom = this.policy && this.policy.promotionFrom ? this.policy.promotionFrom : null;
          this.promotionalTo = this.policy && this.policy.promotionTo ? this.policy.promotionTo : null;
        }
}
```

Call this method on Go Back button click

```
restoreState(){
    this.applyFilter(this.originalApplicationData);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but... how I can achive it in this situation? Because children table components using this object

Comment: I can keep it by JSON.parse(...) But children component uses this.policy as input [groupConfig]="policy?.pricingPolicyConfig?.groupConfig" So to see the changes in that children component i must change values in this.policy. So I dont understand....

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: In this situation when i will change something in my table for example data in input and then go to different component and than go back I will have data without my previous changes.

Comment: Now I had updated the code again and keeping the same reference for `policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig`. It will have reference to original object within the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not using `originalPriceConfig` but `filteredPriceConfig` in `filterTableByChoosenProperty` method, so you're overwriting the value each time you toggle, try this:

```
private filterTableByChoosenProperty(): void {
    const sub: Subscription = this.pricingService.setChoosenProducts.subscribe((toggle: boolean) => {
      this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig = {...this.originalPriceConfig};
      if (toggle) {
        this.filteredPriceConfig = {...this.filterGroupByField('priceConfig', this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig, this.is(this.chosen()))};
                                                                              ^
        this.filteredPriceConfig = {...this.filterGroupByField('subGroup', this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig, (item) => this.checkIfPriceConfigHasElements(item.priceConfig) || this.checkIfGroupArrayHasElements(item.subGroup))};
                                                                           ^
        this.policy.pricingPolicyConfig.groupConfig = {...this.filteredPriceConfig};
      }
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(sub);
  }
```